# How to store fingerprint scans on my computer instead of inside the scanner?

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I would like to know if there are fingerprint scanners which doesn't save locally their fingerprint data, but they just send raw data to he attached computer.
If yes, which type of scanner should I use? I would prefer to use c# as programming language of the handling application, but as long as handling fingerprints on pc is possible I will learn any language you'll raccomand me

Answer (score 1):

All the fingerprint scanners that I have seen, allow you to save the fingerprint data (locally). Without doing adverts for any readers, the following "desktop" device groups work for a fact, as I have them:
digitalpersona (4000, 4500, 5100), Futronic devices (FS80h, FS88,..), UPEK EikonTouch (I can't locate the model number of the one that I am using.). There are larger, more expensive devices such as the Cross Match L SCAN Patrol, Suprema RealScan-G10, etc. from which iamges can also be read and saved.
The important thing is that SDKs are provided that allow you to interact with the readers: capture fingerprint image data which you can then save to a file or to a database. I am not sure about C# though: my exposure to SDKs is limited to C and Java.